# DirectX 11 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, directx-11

I am just trying to learn DirectX 11 (and no, I am neither interested in OpenGL nor Vulcan) and I am using the latest Windows 10 insider build. I know there is DirectX 12, but from what I have heard, it is more trouble for non-(A)AA than it is worth. I am perfectly aware, that for getting a game up and running, using an already existing game engine like Unreal Engine would be more appropriate. But I am not really interested in getting a working game. I just want something not depreciated and good to replace GDI(+). And I always wanted to learn DirectX anyways. I am using C++ which is by the way may main programming language. As my IDE, I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. I should also add that I am familiar with the Windows API (formerly called Win32 API).

I have access to Allen Sherrod's and Wendy Jones's book Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming and Frank D. Luna's book Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11. But there is a major problem with both: They use the depreciated DirectX 11 June SDK which is incompatible with both the Windows 8 and 10 SDKs. While it is easy to replace the error management code with WinAPI code, I am stuck with:

```
bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader( "SolidGreenColor.fx", "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBuffer );
```

`CompileD3DShader` seems to be non existent. I hadn't much luck with Googling it. But from what I have found, I have concluded, that they have not just renamed it, but replaced it by some other mechanism. Though I am not sure about it. Could anyone help my write that line in an Windows 8/10 compatible way?

And another question, are those books of any use, provided I am not interested in using the old DirectX SDK? I am thinking about looking for good online tutorials. If there aren't any that are good enough, I'd be forced to switch to Luna's DirectX 12 book and to DirectX 12 in general. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a DirectX 12 successor to Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming (There is a book for DirectX 9 and 10 respectively) which I like more (I prefer to learn the basics of the API first, so that I can focus on math afterwards).

Does anybody know a good, comprehensive source to learn "modern" DirectX 11? I am open to both books and online content (including YouTube videos).

**UPDATE 1:**
Given that asking for advice on alternative leaning material seems to not be allowed (I forgot about that, sorry about that) I want to emphasize the most important part of my question.

Are books / online tutorials written for the old Direct X SDK still applicable for Windows 8 / 8.1 / 10 SDKs? I know that I have to use different headers and that some things have been re-named and that the DirectX Error Handling Library has been removed. Apart from the DirectX Error Handling Library, can I just re-name some functions and the code will work or are the differences more substantial?

**UPDATE 2:**
I have found two sources that seem to be more up to date. While I have to give them a closer look, I want to post their links for anybody who has the same problem as me and who can't find proper answers with Google:
http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=111-4-1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416804(v=VS.85).aspx

If those tutorials are up to date, I might be able to figure out if the two books are still useful.

Comment: Sorry, for that. I just thought it would be good to add it. My actual question is, are those books still useful for programming against the Windows 10 SDK and what is the replacement for CompileD3DShader. I have found on the Internet much confusion about this and little to no answers.

Comment: `CompileD3DShader` is a function defined in the book you are reading. It is not a function defined by the DirectX API.

Comment: To set your mind at reast - 12 doesn't totally replace 11 - 11 is something which is still totally relevant and useful on Windows especially in the scenarios you mention.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that. DirectX 12 is meant for the triple A game developers while 11 will still be there for the Indie-Game developers and others who just need to add some graphics to their programs. The problem with DirectX 11 is not the question of depreciation, even if it were, Micrososft's policy of backwards compatibility would make that a non-issue. The problem really is, that the extensive tutorials targeted at beginners have not been updated yet and probably will never be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the various books on Direct3D 11 are still applicable in their coverage of the core API, the concepts, and functionality of how to use DirectX 11. The problems come in due to their use of the now legacy DirectX SDK. Notably D3DX, D3DXMath or XNAMath, and use of the legacy Effects system. That said, you still end up learning how to do Direct3D graphics programming.  I've got a blog post that goes into some detail on the various books with some notes of things to watch out for. See [Book Recommendations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/). Note to self: I should take a look at the Sherrod & Jones book and update the post.

> See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) and in particular [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) on the proper method for 'mixing' the Windows 8.1/10 SDK with the legacy DirectX SDK if you still want to use the older stuff for learning.

A complete guide to how to replace all the legacy DirectX SDK stuff when using the Windows 8.1 SDK or Windows 10 SDK is [Living Without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/). You'll note for the shader compilation API, it links to [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/). As someone noted in the comments, `CompileD3DShader` is just some helper function provided by the book author. These days you can just call `D3DCompileFromFile`. I'm also using [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) which is a good smart-pointer to make use of with modern Direct3D C++ programming.

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <wrl/client.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;
```

...

```
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> shaderBlob;
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> errorBlob;
HRESULT hr = D3DCompileFromFile( L"SolidGreenColor.fx",
    nullptr,
    D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE,
    "VS_Main", "vs_4_0",
    0 /* You probably want to use D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG in debug builds */,
    0,
    shaderBlob.GetAddressOf(),
    errorMsg.GetAddressOf()));

#ifdef _DEBUG
if (errorBlob) 
{ 
    OutputDebugStringA( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( errorBlob->GetBufferPointer() ) ); 
} 
#endif

if (FAILED(hr))
    // Error condition
```

Other useful starting resources for learning Direct3D 11:

[DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)
[Getting Started with Direct3D 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/)
[Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't home for a couple of days. Thanks for the code example. I will have a more detailed look in the next couple of days.